# High load average number but low CPU usage - how to bring the load down without a reboot?

Tags: networking, 16.04, mount, nfs, cpu-load

I maintain over a dozen xubuntu (16.04.6) linux servers for my lab. All of them are interconnected via nfs/autofs/ldap services to form a distributed cluster. It has been working fine, but two days ago, my central server providing ldap+home dir nfs services went down. Without having to make a trip to manually reboot the machines, I managed to log in each machine using a maintenance account, and switched ldap/nfs mounts to a backup server. Most of them were brought alive again without a reboot. I forced unmounting the dead nfs mounts (including user home dir) via `umount -f -l /mount/point`.

However, I noticed that, because the previous nfs mounts were gone, leaving some processes sleep/halt. When I log in these computers, I noticed an unusually high load average number, in the range of 20-100 when typing top, for example:

```
top - 18:30:46 up 50 days, 23:35, 10 users,  load average: 17.59, 17.85, 23.97
Tasks: 494 total,   1 running, 396 sleeping,   0 stopped,  19 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.0 us,  0.5 sy,  0.4 ni, 95.1 id,  1.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16382324 total,  1159748 free,  7052016 used,  8170560 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8458236 total,  7108860 free,  1349376 used.  8296156 avail Mem
```

from the above output, you can see that the load average is high, but CPU is mostly idle. There are 19 zombie programs, and 90% of the processes are sleeping.

another one looks like this

```
top - 18:56:40 up 18 days, 57 min,  9 users,  load average: 25.23, 25.16, 28.13
Tasks: 494 total,   1 running, 377 sleeping,   0 stopped,  40 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.5 us,  0.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 49.0 id, 49.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 32612980 total,  2231320 free, 10522468 used, 19859192 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8458236 total,  8451836 free,     6400 used. 19531452 avail Mem
```

For one of the machines, the load average grew overnight, from 40ish to over 130 this morning. I found it was due to some cron jobs.

I tried to kill the zombies, but it did not work. I saw [this post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/high-load-average-low-cpu-usage-615506/) and successfully killed some of the 'D' (uninterruptible sleep) status processes, that brought the load to around 20-30 range, but still it looks quite high.

I am wondering if there is something I can do to take down these dead/zombie/halt programs. I don't want to do a reboot because it may have the risk not to come back, especially for the alternative ldap/nfs server that I just switch to. These machines are smooth to use despite the high load average. The CPU usage is low, and cpu temperature is low. I am hoping to bring the load back to normal, usually 1 or below 1. Is this possible without a reboot?